# Looping over query, creating objects skipping randomly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database table called "trucks" which has the fields "truck_id", "year", "make", "model", etc.  There are six trucks in the table.

I have a piece of PHP code that loops over each truck and loads it.  At random this morning -- and only this morning -- truck number 4 would not load.

```
$TrucksQuery = Truck::GetTrucks();

while ($TruckRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TrucksQuery))
{
    echo $TruckRow["truck_id"];

    $T  = new Truck();
    $T->Load($TruckRow["truck_id"]);

    var_dump($T);
}
```

The "echo" above was displaying all 6 truck_ids.

The "var_dump" was showing the proper truck object (with fields populated) for all the trucks EXCEPT for truck 4, where everything was NULL as if it hadn't loaded.

I was debugging the code, running the above probably ten times and everything looked fine, but truck 4 would not load.  Then at random, truck 4 started to load.  I undid all my changes so the code looked like the block above, and truck 4 now loads.  I didn't change the database, or change the code but now it works... how can this be?

Querying the database directly worked fine so I don't think it is corrupt.

Thanks.

* EDIT 1 ***

Here is the Truck->Load method:

```
public function Load($truck_id = '')
{
    global $db_link;

    if ($truck_id != '')
        $this->Settruck_id($truck_id);

    //1.
    $QueryString = "SELECT DISTINCT t.*, IFNULL((SELECT ot.truck_return_time
                                                FROM trucks t
                                                JOIN orders_trucks ot ON ot.truck_id = t.truck_id
                                                WHERE NOW() BETWEEN ot.truck_leave_time AND ot.truck_return_time
                                                AND t.truck_id = '".$this->Gettruck_id()."'), 'On hand') AS 'return_time', IFNULL((SELECT truck_leave_time
                                                                                                                                  FROM orders_trucks
                                                                                                                                  WHERE truck_id = '".$this->Gettruck_id()."'
                                                                                                                                  AND truck_leave_time > NOW()
                                                                                                                                  ORDER BY truck_leave_time ASC
                                                                                                                                  LIMIT 1), '') AS 'next_job'
                    FROM trucks t
                    LEFT JOIN orders_trucks ot ON ot.truck_id = t.truck_id
                    WHERE t.truck_id = " . $this->truck_id;

    $Result         = mysqli_query($db_link, $QueryString);
    $ResultArray    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result);

    $this->Settruck_id($ResultArray["truck_id"]);
    //many more Set() calls

    //2.
    $QueryString = "SELECT t.t_name, t.territory_id
                    FROM territories t
                    LEFT JOIN truck_territories tt ON tt.territory_id = t.territory_id
                    LEFT JOIN trucks tr ON tr.truck_id = tt.truck_id
                    WHERE tr.truck_id = '".$this->truck_id."'";

    $Result         = mysqli_query($db_link, $QueryString);
    $TempArray      = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result))
        $TempArray[]    = $row["territory_id"];

    $this->SetTerritoriesArray($TempArray);
}
```

* EDIT 2 ***

This is happening again today, now truck 3 will not load.  Below is what I see when I do a var_dump on each truck... possibly worth noting, look how PHP says "object(Truck)#x" and see that they are not in order, and that the number 7 is used twice (and one is the NULL one):

```
object(Truck)#3 (24) {
  ["truck_id":protected]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["year":protected]=>
  int(4) 2006
}
object(Truck)#4 (24) {
  ["truck_id":protected]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["year":protected]=>
  int(4) 2007
}
object(Truck)#7 (24) {
  ["truck_id":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["year":protected]=>
  NULL
}
object(Truck)#6 (24) {
  ["truck_id":protected]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["year":protected]=>
  int(4) 2007
}
object(Truck)#5 (24) {
  ["truck_id":protected]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["year":protected]=>
  int(4) 2007
}
object(Truck)#11 (24) {
  ["truck_id":protected]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["year":protected]=>
  int(4) 2009
}
object(Truck)#7 (24) {
  ["truck_id":protected]=>
  string(1) "7"
  ["year":protected]=>
  int(4) 2012
}
```

Another note: adding MYSQLI_USE_RESULT to the mysqli_query() for GetTrucks() returned no results, but once I removed it, all trucks were in the results properly.

Comment: Then perhaps you should take a look at your `Truck::Load` method :)

Comment: I ran the queries that are inside Truck::Load directly on the server, and they work fine -- even for truck 4 as the object was empty.

Comment: Does `$T->Load()` return the data or echo it inside the method? If it's returning data, you should assign a variable to it.. Such as `$data = $T->Load([...]); var_dump($data);`

Comment: No it doesnt return anything, or output anything.  It queries the database for that truck's info, then populates the results in itself.

Comment: Can you post the code

Comment: Or, try accessing the property like `$T->truckInfo` or whatnot.

Comment: It may have something to do with result mode on your query. You have one result $TruckRow that you are iterating over. The Truck::Load method is creating another result. See the [resultmode](http://in3.php.net/mysqli_query) parameter

Comment: @Loopo when I added MYSQLI_USE_RESULT to the query inside Truck::GetTrucks(), no results are returned so that can't be good.  I have never used MYSQLI_USE_RESULT before so may be using it wrong, but I think it returns one row at a time instead of all the rows... which doesn't work for me.  Also I don't understand why I only need it here, not for the 100 other queries I wrote.

Comment: I was barking up the wrong tree, you didn't have any code posted at the time, in any case you should be using STORE_RESULT (the default, same as not specifying) just as you have been doing as it turns out

Answer (score 0):

This was a coding problem in the Truck->Load() method.  In the first query, some days one of the inner queries was returning multiple rows, which was breaking the query and preventing the truck from loading.

Since the query looks only at today's date, that is why one day it could work for truck X, and be fine the next day, and then a different truck could have an issue.

As for my statement "Another note: adding MYSQLI_USE_RESULT to the mysqli_query() for GetTrucks() returned no results, but once I removed it, all trucks were in the results properly."  This must have been a coincidence, i.e. without telling me someone modified the truck's schedule (making the inner query only return one result).

Thanks everyone for your help.